# Cast java.sql.Connection to PGConnection

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to upload a file in PostgreSQL using Tomcat:

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")
private DataSource ds;
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

I tried to cast the `conn` object this way:

```
PGConnection pgCon = ((org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection) conn).getInnermostDelegate();
```

I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to org.postgresql.PGConnection
```

I also tried:

```
Connection unwrap = conn.unwrap(Connection.class);
connSec = (org.postgresql.PGConnection) unwrap;
```

I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot unwrap to org.postgresql.PGConnection

LargeObjectManager pgCon = pgCon.getLargeObjectAPI();
```

What is the proper way to implement the code?

P.S

I tried this:

```
PGConnection pgConnection = null;

if (conn.isWrapperFor(PGConnection.class))
{
    pgConnection = conn.unwrap(PGConnection.class);
}

LargeObjectManager lobj = pgConnection.getLargeObjectAPI();
```

But I get NPE at this line `LargeObjectManager lobj = pgConnection.getLargeObjectAPI();`

Comment: You do realize that you don't need the `LargeObjectAPI` just to put files into the database, right? It's meant to be used in rare cases where low level access is needed. If you just want to store files in a database you can use `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream()` and `ResultSet.getBinaryStream()` to retrieve them.

Comment: Well, it will nice if there is a such solution for Java and PostgreSQL. I searched Internet but I found mostly examples with their own JDBC driver. Can you share osme examples, please?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "own JDBC driver". It's standard JDBC functionality that will work on most databases. Now you don't need to do any casting or type checking of the connection anymore. You can find plenty of examples from Google. Good luck, you're going to need a huge amount of it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6):

```
if (dataSource.getConnection().isWrapperFor(PGConnection.class)) {
  PGConnection pgConnection = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(PGConnection.class);
}
```

Comment: I tried this proposal but I get NPE at this line: `LargeObjectManager lobj = pgConnection.getLargeObjectAPI();`

Comment: You are leaking connections. The connection from the `if` will never be closed

Comment: I agree with you Svetlin Zarev.The connection in the i f will not be close.I think it should be place in a try/catch/finally block and be closed in the finally block

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
if (conn.isWrapperFor(org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.class))
        org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection pgConnection=(org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection)((org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection)conn).getInnermostDelegateInternal();
```